# I cannot load @font-face for browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

My css cannot load @font-face, it was work on firefox, then I try to fix the problem 'Not supporting other browsers.' And now It did not work at all.QAQ
I thought it is because the *.otf file convert to *.woff format not supporting in zh-hant. But I checked several times. it did not load to the part in English.
So I do need help.

```
@font-face {
          font-family: "CJK-Regular";
          font-display: swap;
          src: url(https://time-sight.com/service/wp-includes/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.eot);
          src: url(https://time-sight.com/service/wp-includes/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://time-sight.com/service/wp-includes/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("https://time-sight.com/service/wp-includes/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://time-sight.com/service/wp-includes/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf") format("opentype");}
```

.alt-font{font-family:'CJK-Regular'}
I had tried to figure out on my own but I spent days still zero progress.

Comment: I had check the following:1.all font files is exist in my server and name exact the same to my code. 2. all files is set at 644 permission. 3.Upload the files again and convert with different app. 4. Tried include the css file alone  (which only put the part of @font-face ) 5.check it is loaded when I open the chrome->F12->Source-> file did load in the source lists 6. whether using the ",' , (none) to quoting the url abs path. I have to say I have no clue what to do. So I have to post these for help

Comment: Please include what you mentioned in your comment, in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had check everything again. And I found out it is because the converter is not support traditional Chinese. So I find exe:'FontCreater' to convert my file thought it needs to buy lience.
Good news is it work.